# Get an object from the Unity container where the interface is InterfaceA<InterfaceB> where InterfaceB is variable

Tags: c#, unity-container

I'm trying to make some C# code less verbose but I've run into a problem with using Unity to retrieve objects based on an interface like this:

```
    public interface IMessagesHandler<T>
```

Leading to several classes implementing this interface defined as followed:

```
public class AmendDataTypeHandler : IMessageHandler<IAmendDataType>
```

So yes, IAmendDataType is an interface.

Hence, when I use the Unity Container it is in this form:

```
var amendDataTypeHandler = IoC.Container.Resolve<IMessageHandler<IAmendDataType>>();
```

The problem is I have multiple similar classes for each 'DataType'. I have that DataType as a variable of type Type. What I can't see is how to retrieve the appropriate IMessageHandler implementation.

For a conventional interface that doesn't act on Type T I could just use:

```
var conventionalImplementation = IoC.Container.Resolve(type_variable_containing_the_interface);
```

But I cannot see a way to adapt this for my situation nor can I find examples online (partly maybe because I cannot work out how to describe InterfaceA<T> in google to find them)

In the meantime, I have a large switch statement based on the type being passed in which is just very ugly and hard to maintain code.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to use IoC Container within **Unity3D game engine** or are you referring to [unity container](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity) and have just used a wrong tag with your question?

Comment: Oh bugger, thank you. It autosuggested that tag and I just assumed it was some long terminology for the Unity stuff in C#! I will amend. @PasiÖsterman

Comment: Not a unity developer so it's hard to actually give you a concrete answer for this, but I'd suggest you need to look at using reflection to do that